# How do I fix a long-polling outstanding connections error

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying out [the firebase tutorial](http://www.firebase.com/tutorial/) and it throws this error in Firefox:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/javascript: "http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js".
firebase.js:1Uncaught Error: Firebase INTERNAL ERROR:Long-polling connection established, but outstandingConnections is 0.  Should be 1 now.
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Here is a more detailed traceback from firebug: http://content.screencast.com/users/metaperl/folders/Jing/media/ce540d1e-526c-4d3a-a5d6-183647114d36/2012-04-14_2004.png

Comment: And  [here](http://pastie.org/3790630) are my request headers.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase just pushed out an update that may have fixed this.  Can you try again and report back if you're still seeing issues?